# Show that there exists a $g \in L^1(m)$ s.t. $\phi (F(x))=\int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt$, where $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$ and suppose $f \in L^1(m)$ and let $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt$. Suppose $\phi$ is a Lipschitz function. Show that there exists a $g \in L^1(m)$ s.t. $\phi (F(x))=\int_{0}^{x} g(t)dt$

Not sure how to use the Lipschitz condition here.

Comment: Hint: By one of the big theorems, you only need to show that $\phi\circ F$ is a _________ function...

Comment: you mean AC function?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich So by the condition of $\phi$ being Lipschitz, we can actually show that $\phi \circ F$ is also a Lipschitz function, given on each small open interval $f$ is bounded. And hence $\phi \circ F$ is of course AC function. (given the value of $\phi \circ F(0)=0$). I'm not sure whether I understand it right. Thank you!

Comment: Well no, it's not going to follow that $\phi\circ F$ is Lipschitz - if you write out the argument carefully you'll find an error. But it's easy to show that $F$ absolutely continuous and $\phi$ Lipschitz implies that $\phi\circ F$ is AC. Use the _definition_ of AC - that thing with the $\epsilon$ and the $\delta$...